# Performance of basic operations

Tags: tensorflow

I have prepared a TensorFlow implementation of a machine learning algorithm: such implementation is incredibly slow. Unfortunately, I am not able to see where I made mistakes, so came here asking.

Let's say that I have quite a lot of parameters whose value depends on a single variable, like, e.g., the epoch.

For example, I have this parameter:

```
sSigma = tf.maximum(
     tf.multiply(sSigma0, tf.exp(-tf.divide(epoch,sSigmaTau))),
     sSigmaMin, name='s_sigma')
```

The value `sSigma` is used for every input example of each epoch and is computed as a function of the variable `epoch` (`sSigma0, sSigmaTau, sSigmaMin` are `tf.constant`).

I would like to ask:

- is it evaluated each time it is used? Is it evaluated only once after the variable `epoch` changes its value and then cached?
- how should I use this type of parameters?

  - How it is implemented now
  - Use a `tf.placeholder` `epoch` instead of a `tf.Variable`
  - Use it as a variable and set its value with a `tf.assign` at the beginning of each epoch?

---

Simple code for the question: how many times is the op `maxInA` executed?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.device("gpu:0"):
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    a = tf.Variable([ [2, 100, 4], [1, 200, 3]], dtype=tf.float64, name='matrix_a')

    maxIdx = tf.arg_max(a, 0)

    maxInA = tf.reduce_max(a) # <---

    op1 = 2 * maxInA
    op2 = 3 * maxInA

    mainOp = op1 + op2

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print('1) Index with max value - should be [0 1 0]')
    print(maxIdx.eval())

    print('2) Using max twice - should be 1000')
    print(mainOp.eval())
```

Comment: provide a link to a stripped down version of your code that highlights the problem.  You've asked a lot of questions, please consider moving some to another post

Comment: In your example, `maxInA` will be evaluated exactly once --- during the last `mainOp.eval()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your question correctly, but here is my shot.

The value of the variable is evaluated once, no matter how many other variables depend on it. If for example TF created a following graph for you:

[image]

the value of variable 2 will be calculated once and then used to cacluate 3, 4 and 5. Moreover, 3 will not be calculated before 4 and 6 are.

For more details how it is done, read [this paper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf).